# Maven Installation Issues Windows 8

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

Hello I'm trying to install MAVEN on my Windows machine. This is specifically for working with Google App Engine. Although I have followed the directions for general installation, I am getting this error. This is actually part of a tutorial provided by Lynda.com that I am following but unsuccessfully.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\farhan ishraq>cd Downloads

C:\Users\farhan ishraq\Downloads>cd appengine-try-java

C:\Users\farhan ishraq\Downloads\appengine-try-java>cd appengine-try-java

C:\Users\farhan ishraq\Downloads\appengine-try-java\appengine-try-java>set PATH = "c\program files\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin";%PATH%

C:\Users\farhan ishraq\Downloads\appengine-try-java\appengine-try-java>mvn package
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\farhan ishraq\Downloads\appengine-try-java\appengine-try-java>
```

Comment: Hi Farhan your PATH should be set like so: set PATH="c:\program files\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin;%PATH%". Path doesn't like quotation marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstall your maven.
- Download Maven
- Unzip
- Set environment variance. (Let's set `%M2_HOME%`, then add to `%path%` value `%M2_HOME%/bin`)
- Check Maven install result: Call `cmd`, run command: `mvn -version`
- Because you use Google App Engine, ideally, Integration Mave with Eclipse.
- Create Google App Engine project by using maven with **archetype**, then import to Eclipse.
- Deploy to Google App Engine.

For only Maven up and running, nice tutorial for you: http://youtu.be/Jtj-0yhox5s